# Does CFRetain keep a bridged ObjC object alive?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I'm using ARC and I have an object whose reference must be passed to a struct:

```
myStruct->myObject = (__bridge void *)self;
```

There are cases where all standard references other than the one in this struct will have passed out of scope, but I still want the struct to keep the object's retain count from hitting 0.

Can I just do this? :

```
CFRetain(myStruct->myObject);
```

and then later when I'm destroying my struct just call

```
CFRelease(myStruct->myObject);
```

These are getting called on the void* bridged reference, and I'm not sure if they keep that actual Objective-C class alive.

Comment: This can be risky as written if ARC decides it can deallocate your object before you call CFRetain(). CFBridgingRetain() safely avoids that window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that works. Note that you can also write

```
myStruct->myObject = CFBridgingRetain(self);
```

to cast the Objective-C object to a `const void *` and "take ownership".